# How to compile an old version of F# using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, f#, visual-studio-2005, compatibility

I am trying to learn F#, and I was looking into a Suduko Solver program [Link is here] (http://www.ffconsultancy.com/dotnet/fsharp/sudoku/code/1/sudoku.fs)! The original program was developed in Visual Studio 2005;but when I tried to build it again using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, I got some errors. I manually added references to System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms, but VS2010 still does not seem to recognize Idoms.
Any ideas how I can get this program to compile under VS2010?

Comment: Could you want to list the errors you get?

Comment: Here is the list of errors: 
error FS0039: The value or constructor 'string_of_int' is not defined
error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Byte' is not defined
error FS0043: Method or object constructor 'op_ArrayLookup' not found
error FS0039: The value or constructor 'init_control' is not defined
error FS0039: The namespace or module 'IEnumerable' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Fixing the error messages

The following replacements need to be made

```
n -> string_of_int n : n->n.ToString()
Byte.of_int 0        : 0uy
IEnumurable          : Seq
m.(y).(i)            : m.[y].[i] //this appears with similar syntax a few times - just need to change round to square brackets
```

not sure why you are getting `init_control` is not defined it might be okay once the other stuff is fixed.

Comment: Thank you John :) I think I might wanna look into more details about the newest F# versions :)